# using a single MySQL query for dynamic results

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which i want to try and make dynamic if possible, if thats even the right way to describe this problem I'm having. Basically i want the products_play.sell > 'XX' to change depending on what the products_play.category_id is.

so if the category_id is 101 or 102 i want products_play.sell > '1.50', if the category_id is 201 or 202 i want the products_play.sell > '1.00'

So I'm able to set the products_play.sell filter based on what the category_id is. I don't mind having an array $filter['101'] = "1.50"; $filter['201'] = "1.00";

The records in the database all have a timestamp and when a batch of 10 have been updated, it the grabs the next oldest records and updates them and so forth.

```
SELECT
                products_amazon.asin AS asin
            FROM
                products_amazon, products_play
            WHERE
                products_play.sell > '1.50' AND
                products_amazon.ean_crumb = products_play.ean AND
                products_play.category_id IN (101,102,103,201,202,203,303,404) AND
                products_amazon.asin NOT IN ('','X') AND
                products_amazon.asin NOT LIKE '%:%' AND
                products_amazon.timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE))
            LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should learn to write queries with tale aliases and proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT a.asin AS asin
FROM products_amazon a JOIN
     products_play p
     ON a.ean_crumb = p.ean
WHERE p.sell > 1.50 AND
      p.category_id IN (101,102,103,201,202,203,303,404) AND
      a.asin NOT IN ('','X') AND
      a.asin NOT LIKE '%:%' AND
      a.timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 60 MINUTE))
LIMIT 10;
```

Then you can do what you want with basic boolean logic.  Here is how the `where` clause begins:

```
WHERE ((p.category_id in (101, 102) and p.sell > 1.50) OR
       (p.category_id in (201, 202) and p.sell > 1.00) OR
       p.sell > 1.50
      ) AND  . . .
```

I added the third condition, because you do not say what to do for the other values of category.

Also, note that you do not need single quotes for numeric constants.